# Извлечение data-text при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет!
Нужна помощь с извлечением data со span.

Есть условный span: `<span data-text="27">27</span>`

На данный момент из него извлекается текст, а не data, вот отрывок кода:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $("table .views-field-field-diameter span").each(function(i){
               diametr.push($(this).text());
            });
        });
```

Как можно это реализовать не нарушив работу скрипта? 
Ниже скрипт целиком:

Заранее спасибо!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var diametr = new Array();
    var stal = new Array();
    var stenka = new Array();
    var resultDiametr = [];
    var resultStal = [];
    var resultStenka = [];
    var obj1 = {};
    var obj2 = {};
    var obj3 = {};


        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("table .views-field-field-diameter span").each(function(i){
               diametr.push($(this).text());
            });
        });



        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("table .views-field-field-stal span").each(function(i){
               stal.push($(this).text());
            });
        });



        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("table .views-field-field-stenka span").each(function(i){
               stenka.push($(this).text());
            });
        });

            $(document).ready(function() { 

                    for(var i = 0; i < diametr.length; i++) {
                        obj1[diametr[i]] = diametr[i];
                    }

                    for(var i in obj1) {
                       resultDiametr.push(obj1[i])
                    }

                    return resultDiametr;

            });



            $(document).ready(function() { 

                    for(var i = 0; i < stal.length; i++) {
                        obj2[stal[i]] = stal[i];
                    }

                    for(var i in obj2) {
                       resultStal.push(obj2[i])
                    }

                    return resultStal;

            });




            $(document).ready(function() { 

                    for(var i = 0; i < stenka.length; i++) {
                        obj3[stenka[i]] = stenka[i];
                    }

                    for(var i in obj3) {
                       resultStenka.push(obj3[i])
                    }

                    return resultStenka;

            });





    console.log(resultDiametr);
    console.log(resultStal);
    console.log(resultStenka);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
diametr.push($(this).attr('data-text'));
```